# extra sql query or extra 8 fields (performance)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this situation when users clients are stored on a database
and things such as their full names, address, state, zip, country, email 
are present.

```
clients_table
client_id, client_name, client_address, client_state ...etc
```

Members can sell to an existing client or to a new client (unsaved data)
and I must store the transaction on the database.

I have thought of the approach NUMBER 1

```
transactions_table
trxid, client_id, client_name, client_address, client_state ...etc
```

where `client`_id refers to `client`_id on `clients_table`

To avoid putting dublicate data on the database, when the transactions
are fetched I make 2 queries.
-The **first query** checks whether `client_id` on `transactions_table`
is null or not. If it's not null then, the client already exists on the database.
In this case a **second query** is made to fetch client data of client
with that specific id, on `clients_table`

-If instead `client_id` on `transactions_table` is null it means that the client data is not stored (guest client)
and all the available data is stored on the transaction table.

This way I make an extra query when a client_id exists but avoid entering the same client data
over and over and over.


METHOD NUMBER 2
Instead of checking if the transaction belongs to a saved client or not
I just store the client data ALWAYS inside transactions_table so I will
have a very large, multimple times dublicated table.



What do you guys think? Should I go for method 1 or two?

Comment: METHOD NUMBER 3 - learn how to use `JOIN`'s

Comment: Can you explain a scenario? The user will deal with REGISTERED clients and guest clients.

Comment: So is there any use for the JOIN query if the client_id on transactions table is empty?

Comment: You can learn Normalization in sql. Dulicate data should not big issue but when your data large that time to effected performance

Comment: Why not make sure the client is in the `clients_table` (and that way has an id) BEFORE saving the transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have now is good, you should always try to avoid repeated data.

However, you don't have to write two queries. You can use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) to pull all transactions and clients, regardless of whether there is a client associated with a transaction.

When you read the data, you can check if the client_id column is null. If it is, don't bother to read from the other columns. If it's not null, you can read from them.

Comment: Is left join better than having 1-2 queries (the second query runs only if the client_id is not empty), performance-wise?

Comment: It is always a good idea to reduce calls to the database when possible.

Comment: The left join will make practically 2 queries every time where instead the way I thought, will make 2 queries only if the first query determines that client_id is empty. Am I correct or I haven't grasped the concept of a left join. Sorry I havent used joins much....

Comment: If you write a query that uses a left join, it is only one query. It will pull the client data if it is there. If it is not, the necessary columns in your select clause will be null.

Comment: Do you care to give a sample piece of code with the left join method you proposed? Thank you.

Comment: @user3772 let me know if you have any questions about this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1938/1